# Discord Bot Music(discord.js v13)

Tags: discord.js

I want to make my own discord bot music, however due to recently discord.js upgrading to V13 all the V12 codes doesn't work can someone help me?I want the discord to join voice channel, put musics from youtube by searching your message and selecting the first result.

Answer (score 1):

there is a package that searches on youtube and soon on Spotify and Soundcloud and more, it's developed by a friend of mine, here is the link:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@koenie06/discord.js-music

The package has a lot of functions that allow you to customize your code, also checking methods such as `isPaused()` to check if the song is already paused as an example, and got events such as `finish`, `addSong`, `songPlay`

I hope you found this helpful